# Как Bootstrap переключается между размерами экранов (md-xs)

Tags: css, bootstrap

За счет каких свойств CSS это возможно? С JS я представляю как, какой нибудь `if экран_широкий { свойства; } else { свойства_для телефонов; }`, ну и в таком духе. Но насколько я знаю в css такого нет. За счет чего достигается эффект, что при изменении ширины браузера свойства неожиданно начинают браться из xs а не из md например и container начинает растягиваться на весь экран?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В бутстрапе адаптивность достигается за счет медиа запросов. Они прописываются в стилях css. Внешний вид страницы напрямую зависит от шрины окна баузера, в том числе от ширины окна браузера устройства. Так как ширины на телефоны, планшеты и мониторы чаще всего в одном диапазоне, то их делят только по размерам. Вот например [дефолтные свойства сетки бутстрапа 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

[image: bootstrap 3 grid options]

или [вот](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) в 4-ом 
breakpoints тоже с помощью медиа запросов, вот так это выглядит внутри css:

[image: bootstrap 4 responsive breakpoints]

Answer (score 4):

[Медіа запроси](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

например:

```
 @media (max-width: 600px){
 какойто селектор {
   название свойства: значение свойства;
  }
}
```